# Issue with Blazorstrap setup

Tags: blazor-webassembly, blazorstrap

I am getting the following error while trying to use BlazorstrapV5 in a Blazor WASM project.

> Unhandled exception rendering component: Cannot provide a value for
> property 'BlazorStrapSrc' on type 'BlazorStrap.V5.BSContainer'. There
> is no registered service of type 'BlazorStrap.IBlazorStrap'.

I have setup the project as described in [this document](https://blazorstrap.io/V5/V5)

Comment: Have you added this line **builder.Services.AddBlazorStrap();** in the Program.cs file?